# Auto-create the task's CWD folder with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I am creating a C++ project using Visual Studio Code as my IDE and cmake as my build toolchain. Using the "official" [CMake Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools&ssr=false#overview), I can do an "in-tree" compilation :

```
myComplexProjectName/
  include/
  src/
  build/ <--Created by CMake
```

However, I would like to do an out-of-tree compilation like this:

```
~/Documents/
  Projets/
    ...
      myComplexProjectName/
  builds/
    myComplexProjectName/
```

The `~/Documents/builds/` folder already exists.

I am trying to use Visual Studio Code's tasks to implement this configuration. I tried the following `tasks.json` configuration:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build Cpp CAN Parser static library",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cmake",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "~/Documents/builds/${workspaceFolderBasename}/"
            },
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
        }
    ]
}
```

to which I get the following error:

```
> Executing task: cmake /home/<username>/Documents/Projets/CAN/myComplexProjectName <

The terminal shell CWD "/home/<username>/Documents/Projets/CAN/myComplexProjectName/~/Documents/builds/myComplexProjectName/" does not exist
```

Obviously I could create the output folder myself but is there a way I can automate the folder creation before the task is run ?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a dependency on your task to build the folder, here's what I am using

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Test",
            "type": "shell",
            "dependsOn": "_makebuildfolder",
            "options": {
              "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/work/test/build"
            },
            "command": "pwd",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "test",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
          "label": "_makebuildfolder",
          "type": "shell",
          "command": "mkdir -p ${workspaceFolder}/work/test/build",
          "problemMatcher": [],
          "group": "none"
        }
    ]
}
```